# Import .Sketch into Java program

Tags: java, paintcode, sketch-3

I have a .sketch file that I have been using for design work. I know that there is paintcode for converting that into objective-c etc. however for my assignment I need to write it in java. Hence is there an easy way to import it into a java UI library.

Additional question what Java api should I use for this kind of design work? It is for a desktop program.

Comment: What kind of Java code? PaintCode can export Java for Android.